# Is hiding/logging errors on a PHP server good practice?

Tags: php, error-handling, server

I am trying to deploy a PHP server with php files and a database I received a copy of. However, there are a lot of errors (Mostly from variables used without being declared). Most places I have looked, including the people who built it,  say to turn off display of error messages and put them in a log file. The site works fine when I turn off the display and hide them in a log, but the errors are still there.

The trouble is, there are a LOT of errors. The page content triples in size from the sheer amount of error notices that pop up when I don't turn off front end error display. Is simply hiding the errors in a log something that is actually good practice on a non-development server?

Comment: The errors should be hidden, and logged, in production. But you should also fix the errors.

Comment: Turning errors off can potentially hide genuine errors as opposed to sloppy coding.  If you have a log file full of undefined variable messages then how can you spot something that is failing occasionally.

Comment: Internal errors should never apear to a web user, so yes you should hyde them and print them into log, but also try to fix them or at least control them (but you say they aren't afecting to the functioning so there's no need).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The errors should be hidden and logger into a file as they might sometimes contain information which is better not to show to potential attackers but you should fix them.

If the case you forget constantly to look at that file what I did is having a cronjob to check the error file 4 times a day (during the working hours) and if there were errors send them to you by email and clear the log file. This way you are most likely not to miss any error that happened.

Your goal is having 0 lines (errors and warnings) in that error file so you should be fixing them the sooner the better.

One problem I faced is that after logging the errors of one website created by others I started receiving hundreds of errors every few days. That errors seemed strange as they were all from the same moment and according to the errors that seemed to happen when the user was not logged in and should have been redirected. They were of divisions by 0, undefined vars... There was a location header redirect in that case but still I got tons of errors. The errors helped me find that the code was still being executed after the location redirect so I only had to call `exit()` after the location header to prevent this errors from happening. I would not know they were there if I didn't log them and the server would still be throwing that huge amount of errors while executing that code.

Comment: So, the point of the error log is to fix the errors eventually, eh? Good to know. I guess I should let the folks who gave me the code know they should fix the errors instead of just logging them.

Comment: Yep, I know it's obvious having to fix them but I'm also trying to provide a way of noticing there have been errors without having to look at the file and a possible cause of multiple errors highly ignored. I hope this helps

Comment: @N.MORR You can also set up an error reporting service such as Sentry which shows you the exact state of the application (stack trace, variables, etc.) at the time of the error, and can create aggregated reports and email alerts.